# Error converting data type varchar to numeric. 1-17-2014

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010

I am having a problem inserting a record, the error says, "Error converting data type varchar to numeric."

This is my set of codes:

```
private void btnSearchCustomer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        //Get Customer Records
        DataSet dsCustomer = new DataSet();
        dsCustomer = GetRecords("Customers");

        frmBasicSearch newSearch = new frmBasicSearch();

        newSearch.myDataSet = dsCustomer;
        newSearch.ShowDialog();

        int myRowPosition = newSearch.myRowPosition;

        if (myRowPosition != -1) //will display the value inside the textboxes
        {
            //concuntinated values
            this.txtCustomerNo.Text = dsCustomer.Tables["Customers"].Rows[myRowPosition]["CustomerNo"].ToString();

            this.txtCustomerName.Text = dsCustomer.Tables["Customers"].Rows[myRowPosition]["CustomerName"].ToString();

            this.txtCustomerAddress.Text = dsCustomer.Tables["Customers"].Rows[myRowPosition]["CustomerAddress"].ToString();

            groupProduct(true); //this will activate the buttons from the Product Section
        }

        cn.Close();

        cn.Open();           

        SqlCommand cmdInsert = new SqlCommand();           

        cmdInsert.Connection = cn;
        cmdInsert.Transaction = trnOrder;
        cmdInsert.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmdInsert.CommandText =
            "INSERT INTO ShoppingCart " +
            "(OrderDate, CustomerNo, CustomerName, CustomerAddress, PurchaseOrderNo, AgentNo, AgentName, InvoiceNo, TotalAmount, OrderStatus) " +
            "VALUES ('" +
            dtpOrderDate.Value.Date.ToString() + "', '" +
            txtCustomerNo.Text + "', '" +
            txtCustomerName.Text + "', '" +
            txtCustomerAddress.Text + "', '" +
            txtPONo.Text + "', '0', 'Agent', '" +
            txtInvoiceNo.Text + "', '" +
            lblTotal.Text + "', 'Void'); " +
            "SELECT TOP 1 ShoppingCartNo FROM ShoppingCart " +
            "ORDER BY ShoppingCartNo DESC;";

        int nShoppingCart = Convert.ToInt16(cmdInsert.ExecuteScalar().ToString());

        txtOrderNo.Text = nShoppingCart.ToString();

        cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();

        cn.Close();
}
```

the highlighted part is the

```
int nShoppingCart = Convert.ToInt16(cmdInsert.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
```

I cannot seem to know where is the problem? thank you for your help.

Comment: So what is `cmdInsert.ExecuteScalar().ToString()` returning?

Comment: Are you sure that "lblTotal.Text" contain the right format ? (with "." and not ",")

Comment: 1. Use parameterized SQL rather than building the SQL itself dynamically to pass the values to avoid the SQL injection. 2. Check if you are inserting non integer value to a integer field. 3. Why you are converting cmdInsert.ExecuteScalar().ToString() to int if you are assigning it to textbox?

Comment: Could you provide the table schema you are inserting to?

Comment: because the there is a primary and there is an auto increment of customer no

Answer (score 2):

I think you have taken "CustomerNo" field in database numeric field and you are trying to insert varchar or string value in that field as i am able to see your code in which you are putting "txtCustomerNo.Text" which will contain string value. You should convert your value fisrt in int or whatever you have taken your database field.

Hopefully this will be helpful for you.

Comment: the customerno is in primary key and the isidentidy property is auto incrimented

Answer (score 0):

Can you run the script without the Convert method. Replace it with:

string nShoppingCart = cmdInsert.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

Then see what nShoppingCart value is, and see if that would ever convert to an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding following part

```
Convert.ToInt16(lblTotal.Text)
```

Comment: i think this error occurs due to Datatype mismatch in your Database colonmns and your inputs. check wheather those datatypes and input types match exactly.